# Google robots and no-copy content

Tags: html, css, seo, googlebot

I was wondering about Google robots algorithm an how they read `<div>` content, where I have this configuration in CSS:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
-khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
 -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
 -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
   user-select: none;
```

They will be able to read content from `div`?

Comment: Yes, they will, this only limit a user from _select_ the text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.